# Hiding unique API keys in webOS (Enyo/JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, security, api, webos, enyo

How do I hide my private API keys in/for my webOS - Enyo based apps?

My development has basically come to a halt because of this issue.

Since webOS Enyo (as well as Mojo) is coded in Javascript, any user can plug their device in and easily view my source code. So obviously I can't just stick my keys in there. Even if they are encrypted, my app would have to include the mechanism for decrypting them to make any use of them. I'm looking to hide my private web service API keys (mainly OAuth Twitter, Facebook, Google, etc.) and maybe my AWS private keys.

So far the answers I found have stated that you can't secure anything like a private API key in Javascript. But all of those discussions have been dealing with web applications which have easy alternatives to using Javascript. webOS apps don't really have a pretty alternative to coding simple apps in Javascript.

The only path I see possible is to create a proxy that all of my API calls would pass through. Is that the only feasible or ideal option? If it is, would node.js do the trick for me here?

Any leads, resources, examples, tips, etc. would be greatly appreciated. I feel like the answer should be starring me in the face since so many apps connect to these services nowadays, but I have had no leads. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to SO. You can update your own question by editing it. You can vote for questions (upvote or downvote) and if you get the answer that satisfies your needs and answers your question, you can mark it as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No application of any kind that has client-side private keys like this (other than one that is entirely server-wide) is safe from prying eyes.  This is true of a compiled C++ app for Windows too.  If the application is going to use the private keys directly, then they're in the code or available to the code.  Prying eyes can find them.  Yes, Javascript might make the code a little more accessible, but this not a problem that's new to webOS or Javascript apps.  If Enyo was a PC/Mac cross platform tool, wouldn't you have the same issue with your Twitter keys?

Usually, what is done is the keys are put in some sort of storage mechanism at install time.  On a PC, that might be the registry or some config file.  Does webOS have an install mechanism?  It looks like they have HTML5-type storage - can you store them in there at install time.  They won't be hack-proof (nor would they be on any other platform), but they also won't be lying in your Javascript code either.

The other solution to this is to require your developers to get their own keys to public services like Twitter rather than everyone using your own.  That keeps you from risking your whole platform when there's one bad customer.

If I've misunderstood your situation, feel free to clarify and help me understand better.

Comment: There is no install mechanism for webOS. However, starting with webOS 2.0 a [KeyManager service](https://developer.palm.com/content/api/reference/services/key-manager.html) was introduced. According to the [forums](https://developer.palm.com/distribution/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=15283), you can e-mail the Palm (HP webOS) team to encrypt something (like a key) to include with your app.  I will most likely go with a proxy service for now because I can use it for some additional cool functionality (see the other answer below). I'll probably also use this KeyManager eventually. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

My feeling is that having a proxy is a great idea. The proxy gives you additional benefits of adding user authentication and other functionality without changing the client side.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [Key Manager service](https://developer.palm.com/content/api/reference/services/key-manager.html), which you can use to store your keys without having to code them into your JS files.